# Bad weak_ptr when calling `shared_from_this`

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I've threw together a small class inheriting from `std::enable_shared_form_this` as follows:

```
class Foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
    Foo() = default();
public:
    [[nodiscard]] static auto getInstance()
    {
        static auto f = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
        return f;
    }

    stream construct()
    {
        return stream{ shared_from_this() };
    }
};
```

Whenever I call `construct()`, `bad_weak_ptr exception` is thrown. Can anybody explain why I am observing such behavior?

Compiled with:
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0

Comment: What is `stream`?

Comment: Another class that takes std::shared_ptr<Foo> as a parameter in the constructor with empty body

Comment: Use public Inheritance instead.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) (emphasis is mine)

> **Publicly** inheriting from std::enable_shared_from_this provides the type T with a member function shared_from_this. If an object t of type T is managed by a std::shared_ptr named pt, then calling T::shared_from_this will return a new std::shared_ptr that shares ownership of t with pt.

your inheritance is private, so you violated contract.

Just inherit it public:

```
 class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
```

Comment: Damn missed this part. Thank you! What changes though while publicly inheriting? Does it do something specific during construction?

Comment: @Quest just add public to inheritance, updated answer

Comment: I got that thank you. But can you explain what changes when inheriting publicly vs privately in the background?

Comment: @Quest:  This is all implementation detail, but in most cases, the shared_ptr constructor checks to see if the object being passed in inherits from enable_shared_from_this.  Checking for that inheritance requires that it be both public and unambiguous, otherwise the underlying check will fail, and it'll go down the other path.